# Use WINDOWS key instead of ALT key in xmonad

Tags: emacs, xmonad

I use xmonad + emacs. Both use ALT key heavily. So there are conflicts sometimes.

My keyboard has [WINDOWS key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_key) on it. I would like xmonad to use that key instead of ALT.

My current `~/.xmonad/xmonad.hs` file looks like this

```
import XMonad
import XMonad.Config.Gnome

main = xmonad gnomeConfig
```

How should I change it so that xmonad starts using the WINDOWS key?

e.g. `WINDOWS + 3` will switch to workspace 3 instead of `ALT+3`.

I want xmoand and emacs to live happily together.

Answer (score 15):

```
import XMonad

main = xmonad defaultConfig
        { modMask = mod4Mask -- Use Super instead of Alt
        -- more changes
        }
```

And then press `mod+q`. Thats all.

[copied shamelessly from](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Xmonad/Config_archive#Minimal_xmonad_config_files)

Comment: How would one tweak a Fedora-provided `xmonad.hs` to accomplish this?